# Book about a girl raised on an island she can't leave

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I remember the cover being yellow with the profile of a robot/cyborg on it.

It's about this girl who is on an island with a man who raises her and teaches her. Tells her she can't leave the island because it's not safe. She has some sort of chip in her neck or head or something. Her days are fairly the same.

She ends up getting sisters who are just like her but they end up figuring out that they are a robot and/or that they have a chip in them so they decide to plot and plan a way off of the island.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  (What year?)  Was it in English?

Comment: Did she have very long hair?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might this be ***[The Different Girl](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15721645-the-different-girl)*** (2013) by Gordon Dahlquist...?

Here's the Goodreads synopsis:

> Four nearly identical girls on a desert island. An unexpected new arrival. A gently warped near future where nothing is quite as it seems.
>
> Veronika. Caroline. Isobel. Eleanor. One blond, one brunette, one redhead, one with hair black as tar. Four otherwise identical girls who spend their days in sync, tasked to learn. But when May, a very different kind of girl—the lone survivor of a recent shipwreck—suddenly and mysteriously arrives on the island, an unsettling mirror is about to be held up to the life the girls have never before questioned.

And this is from a Goodreads [reader review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/586185502?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1):

> **Veronika has lived on an island for as long as she can remember, with three other girls, Caroline, Isobel and Eleanor. Their teachers are Irene and Robbert. They observe thing. They are warned to never, ever go near the water. One day, pieces of a shipwreck wash up on shore, and along with them a girl, May. With May's coming, Veronika realizes just how different she and the other girls are, and how dangerous the outside world can be.**
>
> This was...whoa. There is no way to talk about this without lots of spoilers, so just be aware that there are lots of spoilers.
>
> **It doesn't take very long to figure out that Veronika, Caroline, Isobel and Eleanor are not quite...normal. They are not regular girls. Their attention to detail is so focused. The questions that Irene and Robbert ask them are so specific. They take "naps," which seem to happen whenever Irene and Isobel and Robbert need to attend to other things. They don't eat.**
>
> What was interesting about the framing of the book is that **as the reader, you never know more than Veronika does. Ever. Not even at the end. It is completely through Veronika's perspective, which is, of course, a very analytical one, devoid of unnecessary emotion. The term "robot" is never used. Neither is "artificial intelligence" or anything like that. It's not clear if Veronika is completely mechanical. I think so?** We don't know how the girls were made, because Veronika does not know. We don't know how they function, because Veronika doesn't know. It was frustrating at times, not knowing. I wished for an omnipotent narrator who could answer my questions, but I never got one, and a lot of my questions didn't get answered at all.

The cover of this book caught my eye as seeming quite similar to the one you described:

[image]